# VPN (sort of) works in 12.04 but fails in 12.10 with the same settings

Tags: 12.04, 12.10, upgrade, internet, vpn

My university uses a VPN system for internet connections. A couple of days ago I installed 12.04 on my computer and set up the VPN following a guide specific to linux [here](http://www.ncl.ac.uk/itservice/connect/methods/docking/linux/). It would work quite well, but disconnect every now and then, especially when I checked for new updates. After a few reconnections however, it would become stable until I powered down the computer.

On upgrading to 12.10 , the VPN would connect and then fail instantly whenever any network activity was attempted (checking for updates, loading a web page etc). I have now reverted back to 12.04 with a fresh install.

So I guess what I'm asking for is a bit of help as to what I should do next. Reinstall 12.10 and see if the issue disappears? Visit the university's IT helpdesk? My VPN settings are exactly the same as on their guide.

The VPN worked flawlessly with Windows installed. The computer is a HP dc7100 SFF.

Any help would be much appreciated

Thanks in advance

Oli

Answer (score 0):

If you have any connectivity at all then your VPN settings are probably correct. That the connection falls away and that the problem got worse on upgrade to 12.10 support the hypothesis that the problem is with the network driver. Do you have another interface (Wi-Fi or Ethernet) which you are not using to connect to the Internet? Try connecting to the Internet *only* through that other interface and then connecting to the VPN. Does this solve the problem? If so then please file a bug report against the "linux" package at bugs.launchpad.net, describing your symptoms and mentioning the hardware and driver involved.

Comment: I don't have any other interface to connect through I'm afraid, just the Ethernet.

Answer (score 0):

I see the university instructions are a wee bit old. With 12.10 I have found that I get best results with "Allow Stateful Encryption" enabled, especially if the authenticating server is an MS Windows server.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I'll enable it and see if my connection improves